# Transform a single list into a nested list

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested

I want to transform a single array [1,1,1,1,1,1....] into a nested list(?) or multiple arrays like [[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]...]

My code is returning this problem:
`ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`and I believe it's because of that.

Comment: `[[i] for i in l]`.

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Are you using numpy?

Comment: I was using the lists into a  `np.concatenate` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
unnested_l = [1]*20
nest_l = [[x] for x in unnested_l]

nest_l == [[1], [1], ...]   # 20 times
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question says "array", I am providing a solution using NumPy's [newaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis)

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1])
arr = arr[:, None]
print (arr)

# [[1]
#  [1]
#  [1]
#  [1]
#  [1]
#  [1]]
```

Comment: I need the multidimentional array (is that correct) as entrance for another variable. This answer dont transform the original array(list?).

Comment: @Douglas : Just save it after indexing. Check the edited answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
l=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
res=[]
for x in l:
    res.append([x])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]
```